# Binding Issue Knockout Select to Json Returnned from Web.API in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, json, knockout.js

Hope you guys can help me. I've been working through what I'm sure is a very trivial problem but I just can't seem to get it to work. So, what I have is:

I retrieve a list from Web.API using EF

```
 public JsonResult RetrieveAddressTypes()
    {
        var addressTypes = db.AddressTypeDesc.Select(s => new { AddressTypeCode = s.AddressTypeCode, AddressTypeDesc = s.AddressTypeDesc });

        return Json(addressTypes.AsEnumerable(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The in my View Model I am creating an ObervableArray (AddressTypes) to store the data returned above to use in a drop down list. The binding is as follows:

```
<select id="inpAddressType" data-bind="options: AddressTypes, optionsText: 'AddressTypeDesc', optionsValue: 'AddressTypeCode', value: SelectAddressTypeCode"></select>
```

And is bound in my ViewModel using the following:

```
 $.getJSON('api/RetrieveAddressTypes, function (data) {
    AddressTypes(data);
});
```

I also have an observable to store the selected address type which I am hardcoding for now.

```
self.SelectAddressTypeCode = ko.observable(2);
```

This is where I am running into problems, although the bind works in that it is populating my dropdown list I just can't get it to select the value as defined in self.SelectAddressTypeCode.

It's been doing my nut over the last few days so if you could offer any help that would be great!

Cheers

Comment: A couple of points which might help to debug the problem:  (1) I'm not sure how Knockout matches a selected value, whether it uses `==` or `===`, but one thing to look out for here is that your `AddressTypeCode` is an integer, whereas the value which will be returned from the `<select>` will be a string.   (2) Why the single quote marks around `AddressTypeCode` being passed to the `optionsValue` parameter? Doesn't this tell Knockout that it should have a string literal "AddressTypeCode" as the value? Same with the `optionsText` parameter.

Comment: share us a sample json of your ajax return so its easy to check . any console errors ? cheers

Comment: Is `AddressTypes` an observableArray ? it should be like `self.AddressTypes(data)` .

Comment: Ok, so I've changed the binding syntax to what is used [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

Comment: Here is come sample Json from Ajax call: [{"AddressTypeCode":1,"AddressTypeDesc":"Principal Business"},{"AddressTypeCode":2,"AddressTypeDesc":"Registered Office"}]

Comment: Again, for testing purposes I'm just hard coding the selected value just to try and get it to work: Here's is code for new binding:  `<select data-bind="options: AddressTypes,
                   optionsText: function(item) {
                       return item.AddressTypeDesc
                   },
                   optionsValue: function(item) {
                       return item.AddressTypeCode
                   },
                   value:'3'"></select>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, it's happening because you are setting the value of SelectAddressTypeCode before the return of the ajax call. This might help you:

```
//your view model
self.SelectAddressTypeCode = ko.observable();

//your ajax call function
$.getJSON('api/RetrieveAddressTypes, function (data) {
    self.AddressTypes(data);
    self.SelectAddressTypeCode('2'); //set the selectedAddressTypeCode as string, after the populating of addressType.
});
```

For a real scenario this may be a problem because you can't hardcode the assigned value of the select element. In this case you should create a handler to populate the select element with the selected value while the ajax has not returned. Like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.populateInitialValue = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                var bindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
                    options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(bindings.options),
                    optionsValue = bindings.optionsValue,
                    value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(bindings.value),
                    initialValue;

                if (options && !options.length) {
                    if (optionsValue) {
                        initialValue = {};
                        initialValue[optionsValue] = value;
                    }
                    else {
                        initialValue = value;
                    }

                    bindings.options.push(initialValue);
                }
            }
        };
```

HTML:

```
<select id="YourSelectId" name="YourSelectId" data-bind="populateInitialValue: true, options: yourOptions, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', optionsCaption: '- Select -', value: yourSelectedValue"></select>
```